# MCP3021 byte processing

Tags: c

I am using MCP3021 for my ambient light sensor. I am getting bytes successfully on reading but unable to process them properly. I am using MPLABX as my IDE.

My code is as follows,

```
UINT32 res, val, upper, lower;
UINT8  i2cbyte[10];  // I2C values get stored in this one...

// example values : i2cbyte[0]=0x0e, i2cbyte[1]=0x32
upper = i2cbyte[0];  
lower = i2cbyte[1];

val = ( upper << 6) + (lower >> 2);
//after this value is: upper = 0x00000380, lower = 0x01000032 & val is same as lower
```

No idea why variable lower has a 01 in it.Sometimes value is 0x00cccc32.

```
res = upper + lower;  // res = 0x0000320E
res = (3.3/1024) * val;
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If the value of `i2cbyte[1]` (and therefore `lower` too)  is `0x32` then `lower >> 2` should be `0x0a`. How do you check these values? In a debugger? By "printing" (or sending over a serial line etc) the values?

Comment: Well as the  [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21805B.pdf) on page 17 describes the data, it looks like you are decoding it properly (although I would use a bitwise or `|` when combining bytes). What microcontroller are you using ? And what is the code you are using to read the I2C bytes ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in a debugger.

Comment: @LudaOtaku I am using PIC32MX.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I believe you mean that `0x32 >> 2 == 0x0c` (not `0x0a`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I do. :)

Comment: @Abin, supposing that `UINT8` is an unsigned 8-bit integer type and that `UINT32` is an unsigned 32-bit integer type, about all we can say from strictly a C perspective is that the behavior you describe is non-conforming.  Specifically, the result of evaluating the last statement does not conform, both in that `upper` and `lower` are modified, and in that `val` receives the value it does.  It may be that your C implementation is buggy, but I think it's more likely that the code you've presented is not characteristic of the program that's actually running.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you check these values? – Some programmer dude
>
> in a debugger.

You can't take the values shown by the debugger for granted in the sense that a variable could only assume values which would occur in an [abstract machine](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2007/05/16/the-c-abstract-machine/). (An optimizing C compiler may do all kinds of rearrangements to the code, including using unneeded parts of registers for other purposes.) You can rely only on the [observable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/2413201).

That said, it may as well be that your program (which you actually didn't show) indeed overwrites parts of variables, e. g. by overflowing `i2cbyte[10]` when reading data.